# IBM i DB2 catalog tables / search for UNIQUE Keys from Physical Files

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I can already get the information i need via IBM i Command DSPFD. Further down the spool file, i see the UNIQUE information for my PF, and all the necessary key fields(see below, our IBMi's language is german, unfortunately).

Now, can i search for this information via catalog tables in the DB2? What i need to query is
a) is the table marked as UNIQUE?
b) if a is true, show me those UNIQUE key fields.

For Example, i can diplay the columns of my desired table, which is already awesome:
syscolumns2 - Example-SQL:

```sql
 SELECT c.* from qsys2.SYSCOLUMNS2 c
    WHERE TRIM(UPPER(table_name)) = UPPER('GENPF510');
```

source: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm

*Please note, i can't get the information i need via the SYSKEYS table, i already checked this - this table is for informations on indexes, which are not applied on my old PF, in this case (can be added for faster query access).*

```
                                             Spool-Datei anzeigen                                                        
Datei . . . . . :   QPDSPFD                                                                              Seite/Zeile 2/5           
Steuerung . . . .                                                                                        Spalten     1 - 130       
Suchen  . . . . .                                                                                                                  
*...+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+....8....+....9....+....0....+....1....+....2....+....3 
   Wartung des Zugriffspfads . . . . . . . . . : MAINT      *IMMED                                                                 
   Eindeutige Schlüsselwerte erforderlich  . . : UNIQUE     Ja                                                                     
   Zugriffspfad aufgezeichnet  . . . . . . . . :            Nein                                                                   
   Zugriffspfad  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            Geschlüsselt                                                           
   Integritätsart  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            NONE                                                                   
   Anzahl der Schlüsselfelder  . . . . . . . . :              1                                                                    
   Satzformat  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            GENPR510                                                               
     Schlüsselfeld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            ADRE10                                                                 
       Reihenfolge . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            Aufsteigend                                                            
       Vorzeichen angegeben  . . . . . . . . . :            UNSIGNED                                                               
       Zone/Ziffer angegeben . . . . . . . . . :            *NONE                                                                  
       Alternative Sortierfolge  . . . . . . . :            Nein                                                                   
   Sortierfolge  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : SRTSEQ     *HEX                                                                   
   Sprachen-ID . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : LANGID     DEU                                                                    
 Teildateibeschreibung                                                                                                             
   Teildatei . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : MBR        GENPF510                                                               
     Teildateiebenen-ID  . . . . . . . . . . . :            1010412225901                                                          
     Erstellungsdatum der Teildatei  . . . . . :            12.04.01                                                               
     Text 'Beschreibung' . . . . . . . . . . . : TEXT       Adresse                                       /WH                      
                                                                                                                        Weitere ...
F3=Verlassen  F12=Abbrechen   F19=Links   F20=Rechts   F24=Weitere Tasten
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are looking for can be found in QSYS.QADBXREF.

This SQL query gives you a list of all view and logical files with their keys. DBXUNQ = "U" marks unique keys.

```sql
Select DBXFIL , f.DBKFLD, DBKPOS , t.DBXUNQ 
from QSYS.QADBXREF t 
  INNER JOIN QSYS.QADBKFLD  f on DBXFIL = DBKFIL and DBXLIB = DBKLIB 
  INNER JOIN QSYS.QADBFDEP d on d.DBFFDP = t.DBXFIL and d.DBFLIB=t.DBXLIB 
  where d.DBFFIL =  'GENPF510' and d.DBFLIB = 'YOURLIBRARY' 
order by DBXFIL, DBKPOS
```

My times working with BRAIN AS / Infor AS are long gone. So please excuse the 'YOURLIBRARY' placeholder.